# Select day(monday) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a field with `dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss tt`

I want to select only the name of the day

I tried `datepart()` and `day()`

both gave me 1 to 31.

What I want is Monday, Tuesday and so on..

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
```

or

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
```

Comment: That would give me 1 to 7 instead of mon to sun

Comment: @william `SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())` Returns Tuesday for me. What are your language settings? (Or are you talking about `DATEPART`? That doesn't work for me either)

Comment: sry.. I was doing in datepart. Tkz

Answer (score 1):

SQL doesn' have a direct conversion to weekday names but you can workaround like this

> SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Start with Monday
>
> SELECT
>   SUBSTRING('MonTueWedThuFriSatSun', 1 +
>   (DATEPART(weekday,[myfield]) - 1) * 3)

or if you want the long names

> SELECT SUBSTRING('Monday   Tuesday 
>   WednesdayThursday Friday   Saturday
>   Sunday    ', 1 +
>   (DATEPART(weekday,[myfield]) - 1) * 9)

Comment: How can you justify the first sentence when the `DATENAME` answer above seems to do exactly this? Does it not always work? If so in what circumstances?

Comment: @martin Oops, same mistake as william, read DATEPART and skipped DATENAME. My bad

Answer (score 0):

select to_char(col_name, 'DAY') from table_name;

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good practice. Please consider [Explaining how this answers the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)